# Is it there any way to view armatures in blender 2.8?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I have characters with armatures in blender 2.8 and I would like to view the armatures and change the pose. Is it possible with blender 2.8? If yes, how?

Comment: The same way as in 2.79? Turn on x-ray in the armature display properties

Comment: I found out the problem. It is actually a bug. If I open a project which I used to edit with 2.79, where armatures are hidden, and I open it with blender 2.8, the "eye" icon does not work for unhiding them. If I unhide everything in blender 2.79, save it, and open it with blender 2.8, then everything works fine. I was very confused at first, but that solved it for me.

Comment: Thats irritating, you should make sure it has been reported as a bug if you haven't already: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports